# calculate average of cells which depends upon another column cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am looking a way of creating excel vba for calculating average, depends upon another cell

[image]

In above picture, I want calculate average of those cell in column C, where A column has the name on it.In this case, average of cells C6,C7,C8 (and skip C9 and C10)because Name column (Column A) has data in only A6,A7,A8. While calculating I need to count 0 as well.

not getting a way to create formula, tried with `averageif`, but that only check for a specific data

can somebody give a hint to form the this vba function

Comment: Please post what code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISBLANK(A6:A10)=FALSE),--(C6:C10)))/COUNTA(A6:A10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A6:A10,"<>",C6:C10)
```

Comment: it is calculating average of C6:C10 regardless 'A' column data

Comment: This will work if the values in Col A are numbers (you could do a `">0"` criteria) but otherwise it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind, I had manual calculation turned on... Epic fail.  I can't change my vote unless you make an edit to your tho... :(

Comment: @pnuts Make an edit to add some "information" on why this works.  Then I can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can try something like this:

```
Dim lastRowOfColA As Long
lastRowOfColA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row of column A containing data

Dim rowCount As Long 'Number of rows containing data in column C
Dim sum As Long 'The sum of the values in column C

Dim i As Long
For i = 6 To lastRowOfColA
    Dim valOfColA As String
    valOfColA = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Dim valOfColC As String
    If valOfColA <> "" Then
        valOfColC = Cells(i, 3).Value
        If valOfColC <> "" Then
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            sum = sum + valOfColC
        End If
    End If
Next
If rowCount > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Average: " & (sum / rowCount))
Else
    MsgBox ("No rows with data found!")
End If
```

Of course you have to put that in a function and use parameters instead of the hard coded values above.